# Retrieving vertices of raster features using python and GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I have a raster map like the one shown in the picture.
I would like to get the coordinates of the four vertices (A, B, C, D) of the white polygon using python.

The value of the pixels of the white rectangle is 1, black pixels are 0.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps taking the convex hull of the white pixels would give you the information you need

Comment: Hi, is there a python-gdal function that can give me this?

Comment: Try [`band.ReadAsArray()`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Band-class.html#ReadAsArray) to return a numpy array, [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the pixel coordinates of white pixels, and [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) to do the convex hull